# Gstreamer pipeline to convert MPEG-4 video to MPEG-TS format

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, mpeg, mpeg2-ts

I am trying to write gstreamer pipeline to convert mpeg4 video to mpegts format.

I tried below pipeline but no luck

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 -e filesrc location=20200818125158_00001.ts.mp4 ! qtdemux name=mdemux ! \
h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! filesink location=20200818125158_00001.ts
```

I get below error when I execute above pipeline

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:mdemux: Delayed linking failed.
Additional debug info:
./grammar.y(510): gst_parse_no_more_pads (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:mdemux:
failed delayed linking some pad of GstQTDemux named mdem
```

My Input format

```
gst-discoverer-1.0 vid.mp4 
Analyzing file:///vid.mp4
Done discovering file:///vid.mp4

Topology:
  container: Quicktime
    video: MPEG-4 Video (Simple Profile)

Properties:
  Duration: 0:00:07.267000000
  Seekable: yes
  Live: no
  Tags: 
      video codec: MPEG-4 video
      maximum bitrate: 8400000
      bitrate: 298925
      encoder: Lavf57.83.100
      container format: ISO MP4/M4A
```

My target format

```
Topology:
  container: MPEG-2 Transport Stream
    video: H.264 (High Profile)

Properties:
  Duration: 0:00:09.900164000
  Seekable: yes
  Live: no
  Tags: 
      video codec: H.264
```

Comment: The error says file was not found. Are you sure the file is in the right place?

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler I had changed the file name before posting here. I updated the correct error message now. Thanks for pointing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending multiple hours and reading more about gstreamer I figured out correct pipeline. Below pipeline works for me

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=vid.mp4 ! qtdemux ! avdec_mpeg4 ! X264enc ! mpegtsmux  ! filesink location=vid.ts
```

Answer (score 1):

`video codec: MPEG-4 video`

Your video codec in the source file is MPEG-4 Video. That is different from H.264. Try `mpegvideoparse` instead of `h264parse`.

Als `video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream` caps forcing should not be required. The parser and muxer should agree on caps by themselves.

Comment: I changed comment and now getting another error - gst-launch-1.0 -e filesrc location=20200818125158_00001.ts.mp4 ! qtdemux name=mdemux ! \
mpegvideoparse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! filesink location=20200818125158_00001.ts

Comment: WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link mpegvparse0 to mux, mpegvparse0 can't handle caps video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream

Comment: .. and indeed the `mpegvideoparse` under no circumstances is able to convert MPEG-4 Video to H.264.. You will need to transcode if that is what you want..

Comment: I want to save this video file to the MPEG-TS file.

Comment: Remove the `video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream` then. Then you will get MPEG-4 Video in MPEG-TS. But note that this is not H.264 Video in MPEG-TS.

Comment: This doesn't help actually